# Why does Akamai take up to 7 minutes to purge a URL?

Tags: http, squid, akamai

When I purge a URL with the Akamai Luna Control Center tool it says it will take up to 7 minutes. In my tests it takes between 1-180 seconds over 95% of the time.

Why does it take so long? What is the architecture behind Akamai in this regard? Surely there are many edge servers but you can make a multitude of requests to purge all edge servers within seconds so I don't think it is a technical reason.

I am thinking maybe they add your request to a queue and the queue gets run every N seconds and also can only handle X items. So you may get queued up.

Anyways, that is just speculation, does anyone know the real reason why?

Comment: Akamai does. Why do you want to know? :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) may be suitable.

Comment: @codecaster Because when we edit content we want the purge to happen near instant, like a Varnish purge, waiting 7 minutes seems tedious. I would like to know the reason.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I was wondering where to post this, I was originally going to choose Network Engineering and also looked at Webmasters but found SO to have the highest number of posts for an "Akamai" search.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the file from 180,000 servers is definitely time consuming. Akamai is currently working on "Fast Invalidate" for purging, which should bring the time down to seconds instead of minutes.  It's available in Beta right now, for anyone who's interested.

Currently, the CCU V2 API is down to less than 4 minutes in most cases.  I've just written a getting started guide for the CCU API:

https://community.akamai.com/community/developer/blog/2015/08/19/getting-started-with-the-v2-open-ccu-api?sr=stream

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed that the purge response says 240 seconds when initiated through the API. I just sent a request to sign up for the beta of Fast Invalidate. I do hope it is faster than 5 seconds though as other CDNs such as Fastly claim a 150ms purge globally.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple. Your purge has to be executed on thousands and thousands of machines.

Comment: Obviously but this can happen within seconds, technically it doesn't have to take 7 minutes.